# bibliography issues

Tags: bibtex, pdf, emacs

I have a situation where my bibliography is not automatically getting updated. I run within `emacs` and previously used `TeXShop`. I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
$ latex report.tex
$ bibtex report.tex
I couldn't open file name `report.tex.aux'
$ mv report.aux report.tex.aux
$ bibtex report.tex
$ mv report.tex.bbl report.bbl
$ pdflatex report.tex
```

and it worked. So the first issue is that `bibtex` can't parse `.aux`, it requires `.tex.aux` and the second issue I am facing is how to automate this process within `emacs`.

I have also noted that I need to delete all the files except my `.bib` and `.tex` to make this work.

Comment: Try `bibtex report` (no extension)

Comment: That causes issues with `emacs` @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz